Critical temperature reached, shutting down. But system does not shutdown
The system shows these messages in the terminal upon reaching the critical temperature (70c):
acpitz: critical temperature reached, shutting down

reboot: HARDWARE PROTECTION shutdown (Temperature too high), shutting down
However it does not guarantee the system shuts down. In the occasions that is does shutdown the journalctl shows systemd-logind: System is powering down. If not it just shows the message that the critical temperature was reached.
An observation made trying to reproduce the problem: The system seems to shutdown from a critical temperature just fine if the board temperature is low?? Or from a cold boot? If not on for long? I am unsure what exactly is it. But after it has been on for a while and the temperature has risen, it does not shutdown when reaching critical temperature even though the terminal messages about shutting down are shown.
Linux kernel 6.1.22 and systemd 252

Hardware platform?

@Zac67 x86_64 Intel, Xeon E3-1515M v5. But might not be limited to the Xeon E3-1515M, but have not gotten around to verify that.

mainboard / server model?? BIOS version??
